# rails5 sidekiq not running

Tags: redis, scheduler, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5

Something was wrong with sidekiq and sidekiq-scheduler, when I run

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

but I am not found task by webui, like this:

[image: sidekiq/web/stats]

and the sidekiq running, like this:

[image: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml]

**now  below is my config :**

**config/redis.yml**

```
development: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/10'
test: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/10'
production: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/10'
```

**config/initializers/sidekiq.rb**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  redis_config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.to_s + "/config/redis.yml")[Rails.env.to_s]
  redis_conn = proc{
    Redis.new(url: redis_config)
  }
  Sidekiq.configure_client do
    config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 5,&redis_conn)
  end
  Sidekiq.configure_server do
    config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 10,&redis_conn)
  end
  Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { :backtrace => true }

  # start onece job
  SidekiqInitAppJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).perform_later
end
```

**config/sidekiq.yml**

```
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency:  5
:queues:
  - default
  - [mailers,2]
development:
  :concurrency:  5
production:
  :concurrency:  5
# bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

#sidekiq-scheduler
tasks: &tasks

  FetchBaiduHotMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 1 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '热歌榜'
  FetchBaiduNewestMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 2 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '新歌榜'
  BuildSearchMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 3 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '热搜榜'
  FetchBaiduPopMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 4 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '流行榜'
  FetchBaiduKtvMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 5 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: 'KTV'
  FetchBaiduMovieMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 6 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '影视金曲榜'
  FetchBaiduChineseMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 2 * * 7 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '华语金曲榜'
  FetchBaiduForeignMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 1 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '外语金曲榜'
  FetchBaiduClassicMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 2 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '经典老歌榜'
  FetchBaiduRockMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 3 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '摇滚榜'
  FetchBaiduDuetMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 4 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '情歌对唱榜'
  FetchBaiduJazzMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 5 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '爵士榜'
  FetchBaiduNetMusicJob:
#    every: ["10s"]
    cron: '0 0 3 * * 6 Beijing'
    queue: default
    description: '网络红歌榜'

:schedule:
  <<: *tasks
```

**I found it running like this, but in the web-ui cant found  recurring-jobs also **

```
 FetchBaiduNetMusicJob:
         every: ["10s"]
        #cron: '0 0 3 * * 6 Beijing'
        queue: default
        description: '网络红歌榜'
```

and before running sidekiq, I command redis to  **flushall** to drop all data, so what should I do? What did I make **recurring-jobs** with rails make it running between windows and ubuntu?

Please, help me.

Thanks a lot!